# Viber won't start in Ubuntu 15.10 due to missing shared libraries libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 How to fix this?

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, viber

Viber won't start anymore. This is the message I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I found this and other libraries in Ubuntu 14.04 installation so I just copied it to usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. And Viber is working now. Is this acceptable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the missing library:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0
```

That should install the libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 library.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is a little off

The package that needs to be installed is actually

```
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

so

```
`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`
```

Running the accepted answer gave additional error about libgstapp
PS: I do not have enough points to comment, so I answered the question

Comment: On my Lubuntu 17.10, this version of libstreamer isn't maintained anymore. So i used the following workaround:  `wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64.deb  
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer*.deb`   It's now working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this page :
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libgstreamer0.10-dev

for install viber For 64-bit Systems :

```
# wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
# unzip Viber.zip
# cd Viber
# ./Viber.sh
```

or install .deb :

http://www.viber.com/en/products/linux